# Query for generating intersecting rows in two tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB version 10.1.38. I want to select common rows between two tables. I tried (select c,d from t2)
intersect
(select e,f from t3) 
but it works only for version 10.3 and higher. Does anyone has an idea on how to write intersection query for version 10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner join on all columns.

```
SELECT t2.c,
       t2.d
       FROM t2
            INNER JOIN t3
                       ON t3.e = t2.c
                          AND t3.f = t2.d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS:

```
select c, d from t2
where exists (
  select 1 from t3
  where e = t2.c and f = t2.d
)
```

this selects only the rows from `t2` that exist also in `t3`.